# Assign a next day time to variable

Tags: python-3.x

I need to assign a next day time to a variable. (Example, if now Monday,i need to tell to python to about Tuesday 6 a.m. This need to run every days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use timedelta.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date = datetime.now()
delta = timedelta(days=1)
print (date+delta)
```

Do you need time fixed as 6AM?